# Image distorted when it is uploaded and made into a Thumbnail

Tags: php, image, file-upload

All,
I'm uploading an image and then making it a thumbnail for display purposes. I'm using the following code to process my upload:

```
$imageW = $blogOptions['image']['width'];
$imageH = $blogOptions['image']['height'];
$themePath = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/';
$path_to_image_directory = $themePath.'uploads/';  
$path_to_thumbs_directory = $themePath.'uploads/thumbs/';
$fieldname = 'logo';

if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(gif)|(png)|(JPG)$/', $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'])) {
$now = time();
$filename = $now."_".$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];
$source = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'];  
$target = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;  
move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

$file = $path_to_image_directory . $filename;
$x = @getimagesize($file);
switch($x[2]) { 
case 1: 
    $type = "gif";  
    break; 
case 2: 
    $type = "jpeg";
    break; 
case 3: 
    $type = "png";   
    break; 
default: 
    echo "error";
}

if($type == "gif"){
$im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);   
}if($type == "jpeg"){ 
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename); 
}if($type == "png"){ 
$im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);   
} 

$ox = imagesx($im);  
$oy = imagesy($im);  

$nx = $imageW;  
$ny = $imageH;

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);  

imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);  

if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
    if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
        die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
    }   
}

if($type == "gif"){
imagegif($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);   
}if($type == "jpeg"){ 
imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename); 
}if($type == "png"){ 
imagepng($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);  
}
}
}
```

The upload works fine and the file is created successfully however when I display it is the image looks extremely distorted. If I use Wordpress to handle the file upload and create the thumbnail it doesn't look distorted at all. Is there a better method to upload this file or what am I don't wrong to not lose the picture quality?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get your $imageW and $imageH ?

Comment: The script isn't scaling the image, it's simply resizing.  Do some math to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Mathieu There are settings in my Wordpress blog and I pull them in. If you see that at the top of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done any scaling - if you want to have a fixed thumbnail width and height it will be distorted.

To do scaling, do the following:

```
$original_width = imagesx($im);
$original_height = imagesy($im);

$scaling_factor = ($original_width / $desired_width);
$new_width = $desired_width;
$new_height = ($original_height / $scaling_factor);
```

You'd then need to centre the new image and crop it to the desired height (if too tall). If too short, you should re-scale but use the height for the scaling factor, and then centre and crop if too wide.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about recentering the image and doing any cropping if I need to? The image width comes to 150 and the height comes to 100.

Answer (score 1):

If your source size and your destination size don't have the same aspect ratio, image will be distorded.

You could adjust your initial crop with something like (not actually tested):

```
$oy = floor($ox * $ny / $nx);
```